# Adding new target in xcode causes compilation errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have a swift 3 app. After i added an identical new target with an old one I started getting some compilation errors like :

> Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'roundCorners'
>
> Value of type 'UIImageView?' has no member 'circleImage'

The lines of code are:

```
contactImageView.circleImage(borderWidth: 0, withBorderColor: .white)
```

and

```
bottomParentView.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight, .topRight, .topLeft], radius: 10.0)
```

Before adding the new target the above lines where compiling just fine but something has changed.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Swift version of that new target? Is is the same as the previous one?

Comment: Yes it is the same